# Bullet or projectile

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Which one fit better in the context of "Complete the next mission"

> Hit enemies with **bullets** 50 times

or

> Hit enemies with **projectile** 50 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All bullets are projectiles, but not all projectiles are bullets. A cannonball, for example, is a projectile, but not a bullet. On that context, it could be confusing. Consider that even a little stone thrown by hand is technically a projectile.

In that context, and without any more information, I'd rather use just "Hit 50 enemies", unless an enemy can be hit more than once before dying.